# How to remove "figure" in \ref

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I use my friend's template, and I try to create a figure in my document

```
\begin{figure} 
\caption{abc}
\includegraphic{aaaaa.jpg}
\label{abc}
\end{figure}
\ref{abc}
```

I have "Figure I.1 abc" as figure caption (I is chapter number and 1 is figure number".

The problem is: when I ref the figure, I have "Figure I.1" instead of "I.1" only.
I want "I.1" only without the word figure in `\ref`. How can I erase "figure" words in `\ref`?

I see the document class and found this code

```
\renewcommand \thefigure
 {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \figurename\ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fnum@figure{\nobreakspace\thefigure}
```

The document class use `nohyperref` package.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you load the `cleverref` package? The easiest you can do for helping us help you is to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: If not redefined, `\ref{label}` should print *I.1* only, that's why it will be easier to tell you why this is happening if we see what's in your code

Comment: Presumably this was done to put "Figure I.1" in the list of figures.  To preserve that feature, you will have to modify \label (or more specifically \@currentlabel).

Answer (score 2):

What you request is actually the default behaviour if nothing is changed. So, my suggestion would be to revert back to the default definitions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\makeatletter
% Default definitions for \thefigure and \fnum@figure
\renewcommand\thefigure
 {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}

This is a reference to Figure~\ref{test}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption.}\label{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note the difference in the default definitions of `\thefigure` and `\fnum@figure` compared to yours: `\figurename` is removed from `\thefigure` and placed in `\fnum@figure`. This effectively keeps the formatting in the `\caption` the same, but removes it from the `\ref`erence (which uses `\thefigure`), as required.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that without additional modifications (presumably in the unnamed document class) the list of figures is unreadable.

This fix requires adding `\fixlabel` between `\caption` and `\label` in every figure.

```
\documentclass{report}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\renewcommand \thefigure
 {\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \figurename\ \thechapter.\fi \@arabic\c@figure}
\def\fnum@figure{\nobreakspace\thefigure}

\newcommand{\fixlabel}{\def\@currentlabel{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some caption}\fixlabel\label{test}
\end{figure}
This is a reference to \ref{test}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a macro `\Customfigurename{<Argument1>}{<Argument2>}` where the phrase "Figure" that comes from `\thefigure`'s expansion is exchanged
by `<Argument1>` in text that is provided as `<Argument2>`. `<Argument2>` can as well contain things like `\ref{abc}` and `<Argument1>` can be empty which suppresses the phrase "Figure".

Not just suppressing the phrase but offering the possibility of providing another phrase makes sense when using the hyperref package while that other phrase is to be part of the hyperlink created by the hyperref package from the reference.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\Figurenamecustom{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\Figurenamecustom{\@firstofone}%
\newcommand\Customfigurename{}%
\DeclareRobustCommand\Customfigurename[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \DeclareRobustCommand\Figurenamecustom[1]{#1}%
  #2%
  \endgroup
}%
\renewcommand\thefigure{%
  \ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \Figurenamecustom{\figurename\ }\thechapter.\fi 
  \@arabic\c@figure
}%
\def\fnum@figure{\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\begin{figure}
\caption{abc}
%\includegraphic{aaaaa.jpg}
\rule{2cm}{2cm}%
\label{abc}
\end{figure}

\noindent \verb|\ref{abc}| yields:
\ref{abc}

\noindent \verb|\Customfigurename{}{\ref{abc}}| yields:
\Customfigurename{}{\ref{abc}}

\noindent \verb|\Customfigurename{funny figure~}{\ref{abc}}| yields:
\Customfigurename{funny figure~}{\ref{abc}}

\noindent \verb|\thefigure| yields:
\thefigure

\noindent \verb|\Customfigurename{funny figure~}{\thefigure}| yields:
\Customfigurename{funny figure~}{\thefigure}

\noindent \verb|\Customfigurename{}{\thefigure}| yields:
\Customfigurename{}{\thefigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]